# Use shiny input as column name, if null use string

Tags: r, shiny, rlang

I must be missing something small here but I want to use `input$test` as the column name, and default to the string "NEW_COLUMN" if the user does not add that. I wanted to do this by using the `rlang` infix `%||%` where "NEW_COLUMN" is used when there is no `input$test` but this doesn't seem to be working

```
library(shiny)
library(rlang)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("test", "Mutated Column Name")
        ),
        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   colname <- reactive({ 
    # this logic needs to be cleaned up
    input$test %||% sym("NEW_COLUMN")
    })

   output$table <- renderTable({
       iris %>%
        mutate(!!colname() := "test")
   })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Why doesn't this work? Is `input$test` not really `NULL` before the user inputs a value for the `textInput`?

Comment: `input$test` is not `NULL`, it is the empty character string `""`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I checked this printing is_empty(input$test) but it returned FALSE....

Answer (score 1):

The string length of an empty input is 0.

We can create our own infix:

```
`%empty%` <- function (x, y) 
    {
        if (str_length(x) == 0) y else x
}
```

Then use:

```
colname <- reactive({ 
   sym(as.character(input$test)) %empty% sym("NEW_COLUMN")
})
```

Within the app!